# Referencing a variable in a delayed AJAX call correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function, `fetchAlbum`, that sets up a placeholder, makes an AJAX request, and, upon success, revisists its placeholder to update it. It looks like this:

```
function fetchAlbum() {
    albumCounter++;
    var albumElement = $('<div/>', { id: 'albumplaceholder-' + albumCounter }).html('Loading...').appendTo('#results');

    var callbackID = '#albumplaceholder-' + albumCounter;

    imgurJSON = $.ajax({
         //...
         success : function() {
             $(callbackID).html(imgurJSON.responseJSON.data //...);
         }
     });
 }
```

This all works, however if this function is being called repeatedly, it runs into a problem. The `success` function of the AJAX request always seems to reference the very latest `callbackID`, instead of the one intended.

So when there are 3 placeholders created and the ajax results come in, they all reference `#albumplaceholder-3` instead of their respective ones.

How can this be solved? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Thank you for your suggestions, but i ended up solving the problem like this:

Instead of calling the `fetchAlbum()` function every time, i just set up elements like this:

```
<div class="image-album" data-albumid="IMGURID"></div>
```

And used `$('.image-album).each(function(){ ... })` at the very end, going through each placeholder individually, reading the `data-albumid` attribute, making the AJAX request and so on. This maintains the correct closure.

Comment: Instead of having three placeholders, could you not append extra content to 1 placeholder?

Comment: @PhilipClegg No, that's not possible. They are completely seperate and there are multiple other elements in between multiple placeholders.

Comment: Where do you use 'albumID'

Comment: @PhilipClegg Oh right, forget that, its irrelevant here, it is used to call the right imgur album via the AJAX request.

Comment: I would think all those request reference the correct placeholders, but fill all of them with the data from the last `imgurJSON` response?

Comment: once you have done a request, do all three placeholders have the same ID?

Comment: @Bergi Almost, they all reference the last placeholder, and *only* fill it.

Comment: @PhilipClegg No, they do have the correct, ascending IDs in the DOM

Comment: Due to the scope of the `var callbackID = '#albumplaceholder-' + albumCounter;` the value is being overwritten as you loop through and create your placeholders. That is why by the time the `ajax` comes back they all reference the last one you assigned.

Comment: @SandorA Yes, thats what i thought. Now how do i fix this?

Comment: As suggested below, use the `albumID` instead of `albumCounter` and add the `albumID` into your `json` response data. Then you can assign like `$('#albumplaceholder-' + imgurJSON.responseJSON.data.albumID).html(imgurJSON.responseJSON.data //...);`

Comment: Alternatively, if you are simply loading `HTML` into the placeholder you could just use `$(callbackID).load(//...)` once you create the placeholder.

Comment: usually `success : function()` would take an argument `data` containing the response data. : `success : function(data)`
there's no way jQuery could set `imgurJSON.responseJSON.data`
so, you may want to do something like: `$(callbackID).html(data);` in the function body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations, you've been stumped by a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)! This graduates you to the next level of JavaScript developer. This calls for a cup of coffee (it's not even midnight yet).

A closure is when one function is inside another, and the inner function uses a variable from the outer function. In your case, the AJAX success handler is using `albumCounter`.

`albumCounter` only ever has one value. You're not making three copies--each with their own successive values--like you expect. When the ajax calls come back they're all looking at one reference to a value, not their own individual copies. You should make `albumCounter` its own parameter, like `albumId` is, as has been suggested in other answers here.

You can reproduce the behavior like so:

```
var i = 0;
function outerFunction(){
  i++;
  function innerFunction(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(i);
    }, 5000);
  };
  innerFunction(); //execute the inner function
}

outerFunction();
outerFunction();
outerFunction(); //in 5 seconds, logs the number 3, 3 times
```

Instead, do something like this:

```
 function outerFunction(iterator){
   function innerFunction(){
     setTimeout(function(){
       console.log(iterator);
     }, 5000);
  };
  innerFunction(); //execute the inner function
}
 for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
   outerFunction(i); //logs 1, 2, 3 in 5 seconds
}
```

Or in your case

```
function fetchAlbum(albumCounter) { //the outer function

  var albumElement = $('<div/>', { id: 'albumplaceholder-' + albumCounter }).html('Loading...').appendTo('#results');

  var callbackID = '#albumplaceholder-' + albumCounter;

  imgurJSON = $.ajax({ //execute the inner function
     //...
     success : function() { //the inner function
         $(callbackID).html(imgurJSON.responseJSON.data //...);
     }
  });
}

fetchAlbum(1);
fetchAlbum(2); // In other words, something outside of `fetchAlbum()`
fetchAlbum(3); // should oversee which album to fetch.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `albumID` as prefix for `callbackID`  that can also make it unique and solve your issue.

```
var callbackID = '#albumplaceholder-' + albumCounter + "-" + albumID;

var albumElement = $('<div/>', { id: callbackID }).html('Loading...').appendTo('#results');
```

You can also add a timestamp to make it even more unique.

But i will suggest you to rely on `ajax` response, just return response with albumID and handle it like this

```
success : function(res) {
         var id = res.id// {id : albumID}
         $(id).html(imgurJSON.responseJSON.data //...);
```

you get the idea, you need to modify you `var callbackID` accordingly

Comment: Im sorry, what do you mean exactly with "relying on response"?

Comment: you are making an ajax call, so use that ajax response to handle the callbackID by appending an `albumCounter` as get param. share the full `$.ajax` code i will show u

Answer (score 0):

Try changing,

```
albumCounter++;
var albumElement = $('<div/>', { id: 'albumplaceholder-' + albumCounter}).html('Loading...').appendTo('#results');

var callbackID = '#albumplaceholder-' + albumCounter;
```

to

```
    albumCounter++;

    var callbackID = '#albumplaceholder-' + albumCounter;

    var albumElement = $(callbackID).html('Loading...').appendTo('#results');
```